# Drobo system refuses to mount the volume with the data

Tags: mount

I'm asking here about the Drobo itself, not about mounting a share in Linux.

The drobo appears to run some variant of Linux. About three months ago, my drobo indicated a failing drive during a large file copy.  Then within days the whole system failed with bizarre symptoms I won't bother you with. I got the unit replaced under warranty, but the new unit refuses to mount the volume with the data!  I've been trying to get some motion on this from Drobo tech support but it's now been THREE MONTHS since the failure and I don't think we're any closer to recovering anything.  They assure me the data is there, but they don't know why it's not mounting the filesystem.

The only real clue is what I have here: 
They instruct me frequently to have the Drobo in read only mode, and use WinSCP to try and mount the file system according to this procedure:

If the volume is not mounting and you do not see your share, please open terminal on WinSCP (looks like a command line icon) and run the following command:

mount -t ext4 -o ro /dev/sda1 /mnt/DroboFS

This never works.  I don't know enough really to toubleshoot on my own, and I have some 10TB at risk on the system. As far as I can see, we are trying to mount sda1 as DroboFS

The result is "failed with return code 255 and error message mount: mounting /dev/sda1 on mnt/DroboFS failed: Invalid argument.

Not very illuminating to me..  I'm hoping someone out there can guide me on this. Apparently all I need to do is get this mount to happen, then use WinSCP to copy my files to safety, then I can get on with life..

Comment: It's been a month since I last heard from Drobo, four months since this problem started.   I've begun working with software by ReclaiMe, which is making progress.  The data is damaged, but it looks like most of my data is recoverable.